# Python Iteration Homework

Tags: python, math, iteration

I have 2 questions I need to ask for help with. One question I don't entirely understand so if someone could help me to that would be great.

Question One (the one I don't entirely understand):

> One definition of e is

[Formula for e](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DAd4A.png)

> This can be calculated as my_e = 1/math.factorial(0) + 1/math.factorial(1) + 1/math.factorial(2) + 1/math.factorial(3) + …
>
> Let n be the input number of the math.factorial() function. n successively takes on 0, 1, 2, 3 and so on. Find the smallest n such that the absolute value of (my_e – math.e) is less than or equal to 10-10. That is, abs(my_e - math.e) <= (10 ** -10).

I just don't entirely understand what I am being asked to do. Clarification would be great. Thanks!

Question 2:

> Ask the user to type in a series of integers. Sum them up and print out the sum and the number of integers the user has entered.

[My code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MDzXx.png)

So what should happen is after I enter the numbers I want to enter and hit the enter key, it should calculate and print out "sum = 25 count = 3". The screenshot shows what error message I am getting.

Any help you have is welcomed and greatly appreciated.

Comment: We're not going to do your homework for you. How about you take the time to read the rule, [help], [faq], [mcve], and then ask a new question that follows them and then maybe we can help you.

Comment: Also, one question per question, as these two are completely unrelated technically.

Comment: This is a great question to **ask your instructor** or your school's department *tutors* what the assignment is asking you to do. StackOverflow is really not the place for asking clarification on your teacher's homework assignment, the best answer for that would be the person who *assigned the homework to you*. After then, if you have specific difficulties with working out the assignment solution, it's possible to get help here.

Comment: Good luck rewording! See you soon!

Comment: Regarding your second question, your code fails because it is running under Python 2.  `input` in Python 2 is equivalent to `eval(input())` in Python 3.  If you're going to use Python 2, convert `input()` to `raw_input()`.

Comment: Also -- it is a bad idea to use `sum` and `str` for variable names as those names have a built-in meaning.

Comment: Regarding question 1, each iteration gives a closer and closer approximation of  `e`.  At some point that approximation will be really close.  Your professor wants you to find out how many loops it will take to get an approximation of `e` that's within 0.0000000001 of the value of `math.e`.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's two unrelated questions in one and the code producing the error is not included in one of the questions.

Comment: If as @StevenRumbalski suggests you are using Python 2, you will probably run into problems. For one thing, in Python 2, `1/math.factorial(i)` will round to `0`. For another thing, the way that you are using `print` won't work (unless you imported the print function from the future). Are you sure that you are using the same version of Python as the instructor?

Comment: @StevenRumbalski thank you for the input. I changed the interpreter to python3.5 and made a couple of other adjustments that you suggested. It works now. I emailed my teacher (its an online class) and he has not answered after a while. So I greatly appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as you first question goes:

```
>>> import math
>>> math.e
2.718281828459045
>>> sum(1.0/math.factorial(i) for i in range(5))
2.708333333333333
>>> abs(sum(1.0/math.factorial(i) for i in range(5)) - math.e) < 10**-10
False
>>> abs(sum(1.0/math.factorial(i) for i in range(30)) - math.e) < 10**-10
True
```

So, somewhere between `n == 5` and `n == 30` you get 10 decimal places for `e`. Create the sum term by term in a while-loop (instead of by using the sum function as I have, since you are unlikely to have seen that syntax yet). At each pass through the loop, compare the sum with `math.e`. Stop when you get the target accuracy. Return the final `n`.

Comment: Thank you so much! That is even more than I had requested. I understand now. I really do appreciate it, and thank you again!